# How do you use ManyToManyFields between apps without producing circular imports?

Tags: python, django

I have two apps, **users** and **posts**, with the models CustomUser and Block in users, and a model Post in posts. I'd like to created a "bookmarked" ManyToMany field for the User, so that they can bookmark any posts they want. It would look something like:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    neighbors = models.ManyToManyField("CustomUser", blank=True)
    blocks = models.ManyToManyField("Block", blank=True)
    bookmarked = models.ManyToManyField("Post", blank=True)
    ...
```

As you can see, I have quite a few ManyToMany fields already, but they were all for models from the same app **users**. As for my Post class:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
```

I already imported two models from the **users** app, CustomUser and Block, into the **posts** app. I understand that by importing Post into **users'** models.py, it creates a circular import, at least, it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'CustomUser' from partially initialized module 'users.models' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Is there a way to prevent this? I know an option is to just create the bookmarked attribute in the Post model instead of the User model, but I'm reluctant to do so simply because it's a little weird to me personally. Do you know of any other options, or will I have to create the bookmarked attribute in Post as opposed to User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the FK relation by using a string as,

```
author = models.ForeignKey('app_name.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

so that you don't have to import the related model

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I get the error "users.CustomUser.bookmarked: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Post', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
users.CustomUser.bookmarked: (fields.E307) The field users.CustomUser.bookmarked was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.post', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'post'.
users.CustomUser_bookmarked.post: (fields.E307) The field users.CustomUser_bookmarked.post was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.post', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'post'."

Comment: But I have seen this answer work in other posts, so I'm not quite certain what's going on.

Comment: Nevermind! Got it to work by removing the quotations around Post in the bookmarked attribute. Thanks for the help!